# .htaccess remove www and index.php and force to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have this code for

1-remove www from domain

2-remove index.php from end of url

3-force user to ssl

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404.php
```

every thing is ok
but when i go to `www.example.com` in my browser it redirect me to

`https://example.com/404.php`

what is wrong in my code!?

Comment: From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond, notice this `One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive`.  Your last RewriteCond is **after** the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .htaccess like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [R,L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

first remove `www` if exists,

then redirect to `https`,

and finally remove `index.php` if exists
dont forget

i user try `http://www.example.com/index.php` to access your site it will redirect 3 times :|

Comment: is there any way to merge .htaccess roles?